# Ubuntu Server - eth0:0 missing after reboot

Tags: command-line-interface, ubuntu-server

I have a virtual interface for my VPN on my Ubuntu Server VPS. I added this to the /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 172.22.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The problem is, after a reboot, the interface is not added by the system. I have to type:

```
ifconfig eth0:0 172.22.1.1/24
```

manually.

Is it possible to add a virtual interface to the interfaces file, or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I had to add "auto eth0:0" to the file.